# If else in jQuery not working properly

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to change play/pause icon on click. When I click its adding class 'glyphicon-play' but it also going into else and alerting false. What is the problem. Here is fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/283rgpvn/1/

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var play_btn = $('.poem span');
    $(".poem span").on("click",function(){
      if (play_btn.hasClass('glyphicon-pause')) {
        play_btn.removeClass('glyphicon-pause');
        play_btn.addClass('glyphicon-play');
      } else {
        alert(play_btn.hasClass('glyphicon-pause');
        //this statement returning false
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: use this context. change this `var play_btn = $(this);`

Comment: Add `return false;` at the end of the click handler.   Add a `console.log("click")` (don't use an `alert` as it impacts/interrupts events) at the *start* of the handler and you'll likely see that it's running *twice* - so it's going in the `else` because you removed the `-pause` class in the previous iteration, **not** because it's falling into the else.

Comment: Is "span" a class name or are you referring to the DOM element?

Comment: `//this statement returning false` Do you expect it to be something else?! It will be `false` if it's already in the `else` block.

Comment: It seems that `play_btn.hasClass('glyphicon-pause')` is just returning false. Either your `play_btn` var is not pointing to what you want or the condition is not satisfied, that is it does not have class `glyphicon-pause`. 
Need more information before it can be debugged. Can you make a JSFiddle? Or add more code?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/283rgpvn/1/

Comment: Check out the updated version of your fiddle, it works just as expected! https://jsfiddle.net/283rgpvn/3/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "span" is the DOM element, try this:

**HTML:**

```
<span class="poem glyphicon-pause">Play/Pause</span>
```

**The javascript:**

```
$("span.poem").on("click",function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('glyphicon-pause')) {
    console.log("Clicked when the glyphicon-pause class is set!");
    $(this).removeClass('glyphicon-pause');
    $(this).addClass('glyphicon-play');
  } else {
    console.log($(this).hasClass('glyphicon-pause'));
  }
});
```

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/pxmbL2yf/1/

Comment: Ok...this is also working. But if it is going into if part, then why it's executing else part. Inside else I want to change icon to pause by adding glyphicon-pause class

Comment: It will not go into the else part. Only on the second click it will go into the else part. See the fiddle + console for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

@AnnaOleksiuk is right. It simply works as expected. You should check your code and be sure you are not attaching the same event handler twice. Also change your code to the more elegant using toggleClass(). Check the console log after clicking icon, there should be only single "clicked":

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var play_btn = $('.poem span');
    $(".poem span").on("click",function(){
        play_btn.toggleClass('glyphicon-pause').toggleClass('glyphicon-play');
        console.log('clicked');
    });
  });
```

Comment: You need to check if the handler is not executed twice. I've tested my code, it works well.